# TypeScript: Explain behavior of generic function return value

Tags: typescript

I am struggling to understand why TypeScript behaves as described below.

**Code**

```
01| const dictionary: { [key: string]: unknown} = {}
02|
03| function set<T>(key: string, value: T): void {
04|    dictionary[key] = value;
05| }
06|
07| function get<T = unknown>(key: string): T {
08|    return dictionary[key] as T;
09| }
10|
11| set('foo', 'bar');
12|
13| const a: string = get('foo');
14|
15| const _b = get('foo');
16| const b: string = _b;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2FB4CGAnAngLhgbxgG0BrAU1xmgwTAHMBdPAVzBLBAHcwBfGAXgI8AUMIBmrZKjBUyUADwAVAHwAKcpWq06AGhgA3NABtmZPIoCUefSARwCwmE-hIU6bKQoMBB46YDcwiLikm4ydHJKPqzsXGBqGnha9FYwig7OMBhyzBgyiFLuWJ5Y3mgQaYHBEHKqAORiICB1enUARph1FoHCoJCwaElQNPQ+EVD1jc3don3QMAD6bWO1DU1dgXOwbUMjdD5L-kA)

**Behavior**

TS complains about Line 16 but *not* Line 13.

**Expectation**

Because the generic type `T` of the `get` function defaults to `unknown`, my expectation was that both Line 13 and Line 16 would raise TS errors since `unknown` should not be assignable to a variable of type `string`. However, it does not complain about Line 13 and, moreover, if I hover over the `get` function on Line 13 it says that the return value of `get` is a `string` instead of `unknown`.

I've been searching for hours for an explanation for this behavior. I would love some help.

Additionally, as a follow up question, what changes would I need to make to get TypeScript to complain on both lines?

**EDIT**

Sorry, to clarify. I actually WANT TypeScript to fail on both Line 13 & Line 16, forcing me to specify the generic type `string`. In other words, I want it to force me to use `get<string>('foo')`

Comment: Why do you want to use `get<T = unknown>`? how about `get<T>`?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi  You are right. I just added the `T = unknown` explicitly for my explanation.

Comment: This is not type-safe at all; your function `get` promises to return any type `T` that you care to specify, and there will be no type-checking. If I call `get<ProofOfTheRiemannHypothesis>('key')` then your function has to return a value of type `ProofOfTheRiemannHypothesis`; and the function doesn't even *know* that's what it's supposed to return at runtime. What you have written is basically a way to make mistakes and not get warned about them.

Comment: @kaya3  Thanks for the reply. I was hoping someone would tell me I'm doing something stupid.  Yes, I understand your explanation and understand the runtime implication. For more context, we're building a registry with dependency injection capabilities. We don't know actually know what's in the registry since it's populated while wiring up the app. So we're trying to implement a `get` on the registry that forces you to be explicit about the type being returned. i.e. we want TypeScript to force you do `get<SomeServiceType>('someService')` and not allow it to return `unknown` or `any`.

Comment: I see no benefit in forcing people to be explicit about the type, when that type isn't going to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

the `unknown` type is not assignable to any thing else.
Since you are explicitly saying that you will get an string here:

```js
const a: string = get('foo');
```

typescript would think that ok, the `a` variable should be casted to string.
but at the next line, your `get` functions output is going to be the default value for the generic you are providing `T`

```js
const _b = get('foo');
```

and because the `unknown` type is not assignable to anything else rather than itself, you are getting the error.

But here is the solution for you to make it work:

```js
 const _b = get<string>('foo');
```

by doing this you will receive the string as the output and your variable assignment in the next line will be ok:

```js
const b: string = _b; // no error here
```

Comment: Thank for the explanation!  I think that aligns with my understanding.  I made a small edit to the original post. To clarify, I actually want TS to complain on both Line 13 & Line 16, forcing me to use `get<string>('foo')`. Is there any way to do that with generics?

Comment: Is it fair to say that `const foo: string` is equivalent to `get<string>`? What I'm saying is that this may actually be a language feature. This would fail: `const foo: string = get<string>`

Answer (score 0):

The type `unkwown` is not assignable to anything except itself (maybe `any`, I didn't test). However, using `any` as the default type solves your problem:

```
01| const dictionary: { [key: string]: any } = {}
02|
03| function set<T>(key: string, value: T): void {
04|    dictionary[key] = value;
05| }
06|
07| function get<T = any>(key: string): T {
08|    return dictionary[key] as T;
09| }
10|
11| set('foo', 'bar');
12|
13| const a: string = get('foo');
14|
15| const _b = get('foo');
16| const b: string = _b;
```

And I think `any` is more suitable for this kind of scenario, anyway.